# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ado.net

I searched for this kind of problem, but unfortunately didn't find any solution.

When I try to create a contact in my application I get an error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Contacts_UserProfile". The conflict occurred in database "ContactAppContext", table "dbo.UserProfile", column 'UserId'.

I want to associate `UserId` with the `Contacts` table

My tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contacts] (
    [ContactId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [LastName]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Address]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [City]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Phone]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Email]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Contacts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ContactId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Contacts_UserProfile] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] (
    [UserId]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] NVARCHAR (56) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([UserName] ASC)
);
```

As you can see in the picture, `UserId` exists in `UserProfile` table

[image: pic]

So what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**
@Alexander Fedorenko
You mean this code?

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[UserProfile] ON
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId], [UserName]) VALUES (1, N'admin')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId], [UserName]) VALUES (2, N'test')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId], [UserName]) VALUES (3, N'user')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[UserProfile] OFF
```

@Sachin How can I make sure, that when I try to insert in Contact table, it should be present in UserProfile table? I have, for example a user with UserId = 3, who is logged in and when he insert data, created contact would relate to that user.

**EDIT 2**
So when I created an editor field for `UserId` in the view, and it seems to be working, when I specify the `UserId`, and data is created, but I don't want this editor field for `UserId` in Create Contact page exist, because it is inconvenient that a user will write his `UserId`. So is it possible to relate `UserId` to logged in user, for example when he creates data, he doesn't need to specify his `UserId`, instead the record will be automatically saved to a database with his Id?

Comment: make sure whatever userid, you are trying to insert in Contact table, it should be present in UserProfile table. –

Comment: Don't use `NVARCHAR (MAX)` for columns such as first name or email address.

Comment: Please post the actual insert code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either add data to UserProfile table first or to temporary disable foreign key constraint while data is inserted.

Your tables are set so that Contacts table is referencing UserProfile table therefore entry in UserProfile is needed in order to insert Contact.

Look at it this way: How can you know what is going to be UserID you want to enter in Contacts table if you don’t generate it in UserProfile table first?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I understand that, but should I write some method, that adds association between User and Contact when he creates a contact and adds this record into database? Or what you said above is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the UserProfile table first and then the Contacts table.

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you explain what will this give me?

Comment: when creating table Contacts you are referencing another table
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Contacts_UserProfile] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId]
but the table UserProfile does not yet exist